# Editing in Google Chrome Inspector and saving changes

Tags: google-chrome, css

I use the Inspector (<kbd>F12</kbd>) in Google Chrome a lot. I was wondering if there was a way for it to actually save the changes that I make, as opposed to copying them into the CSS file manually for later use.

Does anybody know of a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save your CSS changes from Chrome Dev Tools. Look here [Google I/O 2011: Chrome Dev Tools Reloaded](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg&t=8m20s). Also, check out this presentation from Ilya Grigorik [Wait, Chrome Dev Tools could do THAT?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaneWEqNcpE). Chrome's Developer Tools has a lot of good stuff hidden away.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could that.  I will give it a go.  I would love to develop a built in FTP server that saves directly though!

Answer (score 0):

No.

I looked into this a while back and unfortunately the answer is no. The *inspect element* utility is only intended for developers to test minor tweaks to their code. You will need some other program to actually change your code.

Comment: I take that back. @Ian Atkin has the correct answer.